# what is [a] as a type in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types

This question is about type in Haskell programming language.

When I type

```
:t []
```

I get the return as:

```
[] :: [a]
```

What is `[a]`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Rewriting it like so might make things clearer:

```
[] :: forall a. [a]
```

So, since it doesn't contain any value, haskell can't decide on a type and leaves it open. If you use it in a typed expression, however, like

```
x = []

f :: [Int] -> [Int]
f l = l

y = f x
```

it automatically gets resolved to `[Int]`, since it is used as this type.

Comment: `a` is called a "type variable"

Comment: @Riccardo I know. Did I express myself incorrectly somewhere?

Comment: not at all, you simply forgot to specify how `a` is called :)

Answer (score 5):

It's a placeholder. It basically means any type could go there. In other words, if you had a function

```
someFunc :: [Int] -> ()
```

You could pass `[]` to it because `[]` is `[a]`, which will match `[Int]` (by replacing the `a` placeholder with the concrete `Int` type).

Now if you look at, say, `id`, you'll find it has the type `a -> a`. This means that it's a function that takes an object of *any* type, and returns an object of *the same* type. Interestingly, because the function knows absolutely nothing about the object it's given (since it has no constraints on the type), you know that this function *has* to do either of two things:

1. Return the input object, or
2. Return ⊥ ([bottom](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Bottom)).

Comment: ... `a` in `[a]` is a placeholder (aka a type variable). ... `[]` is of type `[a]` which will match `[Int]` ... . ((Imprecise writing can be extremely confusing for a newbie)). :)